# how to add new JSON Object in PostgreSQL in a text field

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I had a column in PostgreSQL which has text datatype (data text)

the data in this column will be like

```json
[
 {"code":"ABC","Value":"A1"},
 {"code":"Name","Value":"Ramesh"},
 {"code":"Age","paramValue":"24"}
]
```

I need to add new parameter to it such as

```json
{"code":"Mobile","paramValue":"9XXXXXXXXX"}
```

the data would be like

```json
[
 {"code":"ABC","Value":"A1"},
 {"code":"Name","Value":"Ramesh"},
 {"code":"Age","paramValue":"24"},
 {"code":"Mobile","paramValue":"9XXXXXXXXX"}
]
```

I tried many ways but I couldn't succeed
can i get suggestion on this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you also add these attempts you mentioned to the question?

Comment: am sorry i am new PG

first i tried reading json like

SELECT 
   id, 
   data ::json->'"code":"ABC"' as name
FROM my_table;

i am getting error 
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Expected "," or "}", but found ":".

Comment: means you want to add an object in JSON array

Comment: yes, i need an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use  `||` operator. [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)

Considering your structure is always a valid JSON Array stored in text column.

Try This:

```
create table test (id int, json_field text);

insert into test values(1,'[{"code":"ABC","Value":"A1"},
{"code":"Name","Value":"Ramesh"},
{"code":"Age","paramValue":"24"}]');
```

Final Code

```
update test set json_field=
json_field::jsonb || '{"mobile":"kXXXXXXXX"}'
where id=1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=9c973f579ea6fb16ea8104d882fa91d5)